# How to avoid keeping message in endpoint queue when MassTransit State Machine Requests returns Request TimeoutExpired

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a specific scenario in my app , that is when a new user create new Account i need to create a new workspace for him, also in my scenario I have to wait for a workspace to be created to return success to the client saying that his account is created and his workspace is ready

so i used MassTransit Request Method to achieve what I need and its working perfectly as you can see here i am starting my state machine with this request

```
var response = await _prepareAdvertiserAccountRequest.GetResponse<AdvertiserAccountPreparedIE, AdvertiserAccountPreparationFailedIE>(new PrepareAdvertiserAccountIE
            {
                Owner = notification.Owner,
                FirstName = notification.FirstName,
                LastName = notification.LastName,
            });
```

so here is my state machine i am saving the ResponseAddress then the request sending the message and everything letterly working and the request is waiting for the workspace creating then ending the request

```
using MassTransit;
using EventBus.Messages.Events.Identity.AdvertiserSignUpSagaEvents;

namespace Auth.API.StateMachines.AdvertiserAccount
{
    public class AdvertiserAccountStateMachine :
        MassTransitStateMachine<AdvertiserAccountState>
    {
        public AdvertiserAccountStateMachine()
        {
            InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

            Event(() => PrepareAdvertiserAccount, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.Owner));

            Request(() => CreateWorkspaceRequested, x => x.CreateWorkspaceRequestId, x =>
            {
                x.ServiceAddress = new Uri($"queue:create-workspace");
                x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            });


            Initially(
                When(PrepareAdvertiserAccount)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Saga.CreateWorkspaceRequestId = Guid.NewGuid();

                    context.Saga.AccountId = context.Message.Owner;
                    context.Saga.FirstName = context.Message.FirstName;
                    context.Saga.LastName = context.Message.LastName;

                    context.Saga.ResponseAddress = context.ResponseAddress!;
                    context.Saga.RequestId = context.RequestId;
                })
                .Request(CreateWorkspaceRequested, x => x.Init<CreateWorkspaceIE>(new CreateWorkspaceIE
                {
                    Owner = x.Saga.AccountId,
                    FirstName = x.Saga.FirstName,
                    LastName = x.Saga.LastName,
                }))
                .TransitionTo(CreateWorkspaceRequested.Pending));

            During(CreateWorkspaceRequested.Pending,
                When(CreateWorkspaceRequested.Completed)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        context.Saga.WorkspaceId = context.Message.WorkspaceId;
                    })
                    .TransitionTo(PreparationCompleted),
                When(CreateWorkspaceRequested.Faulted)
                    .TransitionTo(PreparationFailed),
                When(CreateWorkspaceRequested.TimeoutExpired)
                    .TransitionTo(PreparationFailed));

        

            WhenEnter(PreparationFailed, x => x.ThenAsync(async context =>
            {
                var endpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(context.Saga.ResponseAddress);
                await endpoint.Send(new AdvertiserAccountPreparationFailedIE(), r => r.RequestId = context.Saga.RequestId);
            }));
            WhenEnter(PreparationCompleted, x => x.ThenAsync(async context =>
            {
                var endpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(context.Saga.ResponseAddress);
                await endpoint.Send(new AdvertiserAccountPreparedIE(), r => r.RequestId = context.Saga.RequestId);
            }).Finalize());

            SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
        }


        public State PreparationFailed { get; set; }
        public State PreparationCompleted { get; set; }

        public State WorkspaceCreated { get; set; }


        public Event<PrepareAdvertiserAccountIE> PrepareAdvertiserAccount { get; set; }
        public Request<AdvertiserAccountState, CreateWorkspaceIE, WorkspaceCreatedIE> CreateWorkspaceRequested { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But my problem is , when the Workspace Service Down (create-workspace) queue will not be consumed so the request will return `CreateWorkspaceRequested.TimeoutExpired` and then the state machine will end the request and return `AdvertiserAccountPreparationFailedIE` event to the Request Client (the one that we started the stated machine with )

but after CreateWorkspaceRequested.TimeoutExpired the `queue:create-workspace (the serviceAddress that State Machine Request Sending to )` is keeping the message with status ready to be consumed when workspace service avalible, i don't need this to be happening , because when CreateWorkspaceRequested.TimeoutExpired is returned i am going to rollback creating the account so no need to create workspace any more

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your request initializer to:

```cs
.Request(CreateWorkspaceRequested, x => x.Init<CreateWorkspaceIE>(new
{
    Owner = x.Saga.AccountId,
    FirstName = x.Saga.FirstName,
    LastName = x.Saga.LastName,
    __TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
}))
```

The TimeToLive header will be set on the outgoing message.